# rewrite data null_data_source to locals - rewrite count to for_each

Tags: count, terraform

```
data "aws_iam_role" "extra_iam_role" {
  count = length(var.s3_permission_extra_roles)
  name  = var.s3_permission_extra_roles[count.index]
}

data "null_data_source" "extra_iam" {
  count = length(var.s3_permission_extra_roles)
  inputs = {
    role_id = "${data.aws_iam_role.extra_iam_role[count.index].unique_id}:*"
  }
}

I want to rewrite that code like this:

data "aws_iam_role" "extra_iam_role" {
  for_each = var.s3_permission_extra_roles
  name  = each.value    
}

# is that correct ?


data "null_data_source" "extra_iam" {
  for_each = var.s3_permission_extra_roles
  inputs = {
    role_id = data.aws_iam_role.extra_iam_role????????
    #what code should be in previous line
  }
}
```

i am clueless here....please help

i want to get rid of that count.index because that cant be used by locals...

i am not sure how to rewrite that count.index into for_each similarity

Answer (score 0):

@kovokilla I believe 'var.s3_permission_extra_roles' is of type set and in that case, in your first code you should do something similar to below

```
data "aws_iam_role" "extra_iam_role" {
  for_each = toset(var.s3_permission_extra_roles)
  name  = each.value    
}
```

and for second block, you can write something similar to below

```
data "null_data_source" "extra_iam" {
  for_each = toset(var.s3_permission_extra_roles)
  inputs = {
    role_id = data.aws_iam_role.extra_iam_role[each.key].unique_id
  }
}
```

Remember to define your 's3_permission_extra_roles' as type set in your variables.tf file

```
variable "s3_permission_extra_roles" {
  description = "s3 permission roles"
  default     = ["role1","role2"]
  type        = set(string)
}
```

Comment: role_id = data.aws_iam_role.extra_iam_role[each.key].unique_id:*

this line is having and error:

line 18: Expected a newline or comma to mark the beginning of the next attribute.

Comment: ```
data "null_data_source" "extra_iam" {
  for_each = toset(var.s3_permission_extra_roles)
  inputs = {
    role_id = data.aws_iam_role.extra_iam_role[each.key].unique_id
  }
}

locals {
  extra_iam_role_id = data.aws_iam_role.extra_iam_role[each.key].unique_id
}```

The "each" object can be used only in "module" or "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set.

Comment: i just modified your query... and i mentioned you need to change your variable type as 'set' for 's3_permission_extra_roles' variable. Plus, try to use 'role_id = data.aws_iam_role.extra_iam_role[each.key].unique_id' alone (remove * at end) and try

Comment: is it possible to share variable.tf file content ?

Comment: in the end i came uo with this:

```
locals {
  extra_iam_final_unique_id = join(
      "\", \"",
      concat(
        data.aws_iam_user.extra_iam_users.*.user_id,
        ["${data.aws_iam_role.vault_cluster_iam_role.unique_id}:*"],
        ["${join(",","${data.aws_iam_role.extra_iam_role.*.unique_id}")}:*"],
        ["${aws_iam_role.replication.unique_id}:*"],
      )
    )
}
```